# get document html and remove elements with no impact on the page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get all the document html in a variable and delete DOM elements inside using jQuery.

for exemple, my document is:

```
<div>aa</div>
<div>bb</div>
```

I use my javascript, I tried something but it didn't works:

```
var doc = $('html').html();
var print = $.parseHTML(doc);
print.remove('div:eq(1)');
```

And I'd like to have:

```
<div>aa</div>
```

In print without removing it from the document

http://jsfiddle.net/VnGeE/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use clone()

```
var doc = $('html').clone();
doc.find('div:eq(1)').remove();
alert(doc.html());
```